# Bootstrap tabs aren't working with AngularJS routes. 'data-target' isn't working too

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-routing

I got this code from the Bootswatch website, it supposed to work just fine :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#other" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
    <p>Tab home!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <p>Tab Profile!</p>
  </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="other">
    <p>Tab Other!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I'm using AngularJS routes, so the `href` links aren't working, I tried to replace `href` with `data-target`, but it doesn't work either. Please help, and is there a simple way to change the Tab class to `active` while active? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look into using [Angular-UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for Bootstrap components like this.  It gives you Bootstrap components like tabs that have been written specifically for AngularJS applications.  Check out the "Tabs" section on that link.

Comment: I wanted another solution but this. But thanks anyway.